# Punctuation questions mark

Tags: punctuation

1  How to do that? 
2  How to approach this? 
Do these sentences need interrogative mark?

In what cases, ? symbol can be avoided? Suppose sentence start with How as in above two sentences.

Comment: **How** to punctuate is a matter of emphasis and context.

Comment: Are they actual questions (what is the best way to do that?) or headings for a description of how to do it? If they are not questions, they don't need a question mark.